# How to translate these wedding introductions into Korean?

Tags: translation, meaning, greeting

A friend of mine is going to marry a Korean husband. She knew I knew Korean so she wanted me to translate some introductory sentences of her wedding, but my Korean is not good enough to translate long sentences. Now, i have these wedding introductions as follow:

> Today we are very happy and very honored to be in attendance by all of you who have not shy away from the distant roads and spend your precious time to attend our children's wedding party. Wishing you delicious and happy. Our family sincerely thanks!

and

> Really thank the host of each family. And now invite the host of each family  goes back to the banquet table to celebrate with all the guests.

Can you translate these sentence into Korean? Thank you!

Comment: What does second introduction means? I couldn't find what does 'host of family' means.... Sorry for my short English. I translated first one, here : `먼 거리에도 불구하고 여러분의 소중한 시간을 들여 저희 아이들의 결혼식에 참여하시어 자리를 빛내주셔서 감사합니다. 맛있게 드시고, 즐거운 시간 보내시기 바랍니다. 다시 한번 진심으로 감사드립니다.`, assume `wishing you delicious` means `enjoy your meal`.

Comment: Thank you. "Host of each family" means "결혼식의 주최/주례 (representatives of the 2 families)", can you help me to translate it? Thank you!

Comment: `representatives of the 2 families`... Maybe that could be `양가 대표` or `혼주`? `주례` is marriage officiant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is my first draft. Something may be omitted or altered.

> 먼 거리에도 불구하고 여러분의 소중한 시간을 들여 저희 아이들의 결혼식에 참여하시어 자리를 빛내주셔서 감사합니다. 맛있게 드시고, 즐거운 시간 보내시기 바랍니다. 다시 한번 진심으로 감사드립니다.

(assume `wishing you delicious` mean `enjoy your meal` or something like it.)

> 양가 대표님께 다시 한번 감사인사 드립니다. 양가 대표님은 다시 연회장으로 돌아가 하객 분들과 함께하시길 바랍니다.

(So this might be wrong. `celebrate with guest` omitted, and it changed to `be with guest`. Someone cross-check this, please.)

My translation may be incorrect, but hope this could help.